# Is the SN1 reaction faster with an axial or equatorial leaving group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, conformers, cyclohexane

[image: 1-(tert-butyl)-4-chlorocyclohexane]

Why does compound **1** undergo the $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reaction faster than **2** even though both proceed *via* the same carbocation intermediate?

Comment: You had the two compounds the wrong way round, by the way. The *cis* diastereomer reacts faster. Also, [please no MathJaX in titles](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/261/is-mathjax-in-titles-a-problem-and-why).

Comment: @orthocresol do you know what the relative rates of solvolysis are for these two compounds?

Comment: @ron I went searching a bit. Can't find anything on the chlorides, but acetolysis of the tosylates proceeds with $k_\mathrm{ax}/k_\mathrm{eq} = 3.24$. [JACS 1955, 77, 5562](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01626a037)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Conformations]

In compund **2**, both substituents can be placed in equatorial positions, whereas in **1** the $\ce{Cl}$ group is forced into an axial position since the bulky *t*-butyl group has to be placed equatorial. This makes compound **1** more unstable (higher energy), leading to a faster rate of formation of the carbocation.

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely that the cyclohexane will adopt a non-chair conformation. The chlorine will just be stuck in an axial position.

Comment: Just to add: an alternative way of looking at it is that, with compound **1**, upon leaving of the $\ce{Cl-}$, there is relief of 1,3-diaxial interactions. But it is really just a different way of describing the same thing.